# Servidor para aplicacion Access VBA

Tags: web, ms-access

Un amigo tiene un negocio y tiene un sistema hecho en VBA..osea usa Access para las tablas obviamente, formularios y reportes, y codifica con VBA.

Le habia propuesto un sistema cliente servidor: Delphi + MySQL. Pero no acepto.

Y quiere crear un servidor para no pasar datos mediante pendrive desde una maquina a otra. Osea seria un disco compartido en Internet o me equivoco? Ya que access no es un motor de base de datos al que se acceda con IP y Puerto. Osea se debe compartir el disco?

Si fuera asi: en caso de que no haya internet se puede guardar en local, o Access queda "pegado" a ese disco en Internet.?

Comment: Lo mas practico es crear la misma base de datos que tiene el archivo access en una de MySQL, luego vincularla por medio de drivers odbc, de esta forma el acceso es por TCP y no por SAMBA (carpeta compartida).
Existe la posibilidad de mejorar el rendimiento a traves de la liberia ADO, pero eso lleva trabajo, tiempo, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Access no es un SGBD, es una Base de Datos local y no puedes acceder a ella directamente a través de internet.

Dentro de una red local puedes acceder a través de un directorio compartido. 
A través de internet tendrás que pensar en algo como Terminal Server o similar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener un disco duro en red, siempre online, donde almacenes la base de datos (back-end) y el front-end en cada uno de los pcs se pueden conectar a él. Eso siempre que estén dentro de una misma red.

Si tuvieses que hacerlo por intener la solución es montar una vpn en el equipo que esté fuera de tu red para que así parezca que están en la misma.

Lo ideal sería montar la base de datos en un server con Mysql y luego, mediante odbc, conectar a esa base de datos.